# Generated WebService Client using Apache Axis2 : Unexpected subelement "categoryType" because some Error happened due to Axis2 Client

Tags: web-services, client, apache-axis

I am using STS(Spring Tool Suite) IDE, Tomcat 7, Spring 4 with Rest (@RestController) , JDK 7 and using Maven project. 
I am calling Axis2 WebService and for that I have generated Axis2 Client using WSDL2Java tool by passing the WSDLLocation URL . Then one Stub(Client) class have been generated and I am trying to retrieve the "catgoryType" Element from the Axis2 Service but I am getting Error and **here is the Exception Logs :**-

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement categoryType
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.fromOM(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:3085)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.findProduct(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:1122)
    at com.webservice.client.SOAPConsumer.getInfo(SOAPConsumer.java:125)
    at com.controller.restcontroller.v1.PINDetailsRestController.getPINResult(PINDetailsRestController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement categoryType
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$ProduceableCategoryIdentifier$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:65481)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$Component$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:38761)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$Product$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:31880)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$FindProductOP$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:56244)
    at com..webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$FindProductResponse$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:44992)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$FindProductResponseE$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:26859)
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.fromOM(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:2986)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement categoryType
    at com.webservice.client.ProductIdentity_7_0Stub$ProduceableCategoryIdentifier$Factory.parse(ProductIdentity_7_0Stub.java:65407)
    ... 46 more
2015-12-03 12:17:31 FATAL SOAPConsumer:133 - Some Error happened due to Axis2 Client
```

As per my observation, in the XSD of calling Axis2 Service , the Element name is **"catgoryType"** but in my application , inside the generated Stub(Client) class, the Element name is "localCategoryType". So my question is how to Map the generated Stub class Element with the XSD Element in the Calling Axis2 Service?

Thanks,